# Recoil Invalid hook call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recoiljs

I try to create application using react and recoil, following official [guide](https://recoiljs.org/docs/introduction/getting-started).  I created react project, deleted all sample code from it and copy-pasted code from the guide. I get following error:

```
react.development.js:207 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
printWarning @ react.development.js:207
error @ react.development.js:181
resolveDispatcher @ react.development.js:1590
useContext @ react.development.js:1600
useStoreRef @ recoil.js:4124
RecoilRoot @ recoil.js:4501
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16175
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20913
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22416
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4161
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4210
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4274
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27405
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26513
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26422
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26390
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25806
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25706
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1616 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (react.development.js:1616:1)
    at useStoreRef (recoil.js:4124:1)
    at RecoilRoot (recoil.js:4501:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4161:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4210:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4274:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27405:1)
useContext @ react.development.js:1616
useStoreRef @ recoil.js:4124
RecoilRoot @ recoil.js:4501
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16175
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20913
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:22416
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4161
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4210
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4274
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27405
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26513
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26422
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26390
recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25806
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25706
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react-dom.development.js:18572 The above error occurred in the <RecoilRoot> component:

    at RecoilRoot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:51544:5)
    at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
logCapturedError @ react-dom.development.js:18572
update.callback @ react-dom.development.js:18605
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:13122
commitUpdateQueue @ react-dom.development.js:13143
commitLayoutEffectOnFiber @ react-dom.development.js:23290
commitLayoutMountEffects_complete @ react-dom.development.js:24578
commitLayoutEffects_begin @ react-dom.development.js:24564
commitLayoutEffects @ react-dom.development.js:24502
commitRootImpl @ react-dom.development.js:26779
commitRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26638
finishConcurrentRender @ react-dom.development.js:25848
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:25765
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
react.development.js:1616 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')
    at useContext (react.development.js:1616:1)
    at useStoreRef (recoil.js:4124:1)
    at RecoilRoot (recoil.js:4501:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16175:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20913:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:22416:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27381:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26513:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26422:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26390:1)
```

My code consists of 2 files:

**index.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import {App} from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

and **App.tsx:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  RecoilRoot,
  atom,
  selector,
  useRecoilState,
  useRecoilValue,
} from 'recoil';

function App() {
  return (
      <RecoilRoot>
        <CharacterCounter />
      </RecoilRoot>
  );
}

const textState = atom({
  key: 'textState', // unique ID (with respect to other atoms/selectors)
  default: '', // default value (aka initial value)
});

function CharacterCounter() {
  return (
      <div>
        <TextInput />
        <CharacterCount />
      </div>
  );
}

function TextInput() {
  const [text, setText] = useRecoilState(textState);

  const onChange = (event:any) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" value={text} onChange={onChange} />
        <br />
        Echo: {text}
      </div>
  );
}

const charCountState = selector({
  key: 'charCountState', // unique ID (with respect to other atoms/selectors)
  get: ({get}) => {
    const text = get(textState);

    return text.length;
  },
});

function CharacterCount() {
  const count = useRecoilValue(charCountState);

  return <>Character Count: {count}</>;
}

export {App}
```

I don't understand what am I doing wrong in such minimal example.

EDIT:
I tried code in sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-liskov-14omc2?file=/src/index.tsx) and it works fine.

EDIT2:
I tried creating new react app several times, pasted code there from various sources with same error. In the end, I just found hello-world app on github which works. I don't know what's the problem with my PC.

Comment: Commenting for updates!

Comment: I faced the same issue when I installed recoil (using npm install) in a different location than the original project.